# AltGr special character binding

Tags: xmodmap

Is there a way to bind AltGr-modifiers to other special characters? I use a UK Macintosh keyboard, but need Norwegian letters. I can access ø and æ with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, but there is no å: /ɔːˀ/. How can I bind this to e.g. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-' ?

I use i3, so I can bind stuff from there too, but Xmodmap would be preffered. Thanks.

Comment: `xmodmap` should be avoided these days; it will not function in Wayland or other post-X11 contexts.  XKB methods will continue to work.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with XKB then? @quixotic

Comment: there are probably already `Compose` sequences to provide the letters you need, so setting a compose key option is probably the easiest existing method.  if compose isn't an option and you need such letters on level3 and 4 you'd probably have to build your own layout overrides.  see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` for existing UK layouts.

Answer (score 2):

```
keycode 34 = bracketleft braceleft aring Aring aring Aring
```

Sets aring (å) so AltGr-[, (its position on a norwegian keyboard).
For ø oslash and æ ae to be placed in the correct position as well, add:

```
keycode 47 = semicolon colon oslash Oslash oslash Oslash
keycode 48 = apostrophe quotedbl ae AE ae AE
```